# just started getting the "validation of viewstate mac" error

Tags: asp.net, macos, viewstate

I have had a site up and running for quite a while, but I've just started getting the MAC failed error. Quite often too. While coding tonight I've noticed it 4 times or so. The host (through someone else) changed servers and we've had a bunch of issues. This started happening since then. What are all the possibilities that it could be on the server end that I could ask? (I don't know all that much about IIS).

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a few error messages would help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the host has changed something.

All posts are signed with the MAC key. In a load balanced solution the servers need to share the key or the MAC validation fails.

Especially if the servers are load balanced and don't share the MAC key.

Comment: what do you mean? Yes to what, that it could be all sorts of reasons with the server? gulp. What can I do? If I tell them the error, will they know or be able to do anything?